# What is the use of from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

Tags: python

I'm learning a bit about the automation of web applications using python 
I came across this module:

`from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys`

What is the meant by keys and use of keys?

Answer (score 3):

The Keys are referring to keyboard keys. It's used to ID the different Keys on the keyboard. Ex: Keys.RETURN means your ENTER key in your keyboard.
These keys can then be used by selenium for keyboard emulation or other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Keys are the buttons on the keyboard and they allow you to simulate some actions. For example, open a new tab in the browser, hit the enter and submit the form.
Here is an example.

```
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't')
```

Comment: what is  +'t' for? Whether it mentions Enter?

Comment: Combination of command key and t key opens a new tab in the browser.